# "name":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","message":"Requested resource ID was not found."

Tags: paypal, sandbox

I can't understand how such a very important method of payment have to few help and is too complicated to use it.

I am trying to complete payments in sandbox in order just to test the "refund" for one of our customers.

Every time I try to refund a payment I have this error.

I have already read and google lost of suggestions for solutions but none of then are clear enough and some other simply do not have any answer.

Is there actually someone from paypal who can help me?

Comment: how you solved it?